# How to pass two parameters to react key attribute

Tags: reactjs

I want to refresh component using key attribute of react but I want pass two parameter to that , is there any way to do that?

Comment: can you provide an example of the code? so that we know what you need

Comment: yes, using template literals do something like this : key={``${param1}${param2}``}

Comment: yes, key={${param1}${param2}} works , thanks so much